# SmartWatch emulator Preference not found when located in subdirectory

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

When I open my Preferences via Smart Extension emulator, under tab Controls, menu Extension Preferences, click SampleControlExtension settings. I get:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.q/com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.q.SamplePreferenceActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This combination does not work in the SmartWatch emulator:

```
   ...
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension"
  android:versionName="1.0.1" android:versionCode="10001">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.EXTENSION_PERMISSION" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".q.SamplePreferenceActivity" android:label="@string/preference_activity_title">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".controlsample.SampleExtensionService" />

    <receiver android:name=".controlsample.ExtensionReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
        ...
```

Looks like a bug in the SmartWatch emulator?

Code [link](https://github.com/powder366/SampleControlExtension.git)

Stacktrace:

```
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:        Unable to find explicit activity class {com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.q/com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension.q.SamplePreferenceActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.emulator.ExtensionPreferenceActivity$1.onPreferenceClick(ExtensionPreferenceActivity.java:87)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:944)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:208)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-21 13:01:05.963: E/AndroidRuntime(3295):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded your example code, imported to eclipse etc etc, but cannot reproduce the issues that you are having. Are you still having them?

And a general comment - the extension that you have implemented is a widget extension, thus it should not be visible in the Control tab of the emulator. So, I am curious how you could find the extension under this tab.

Perhaps you could update your question with some more information, and perhaps more stack trace information?

**Update:**

I have done some tests, and it is evident that the emulator does not behave as it should with regards to the specific circumstances of the example above. I will now check the update schedule of the Smart Extension SDK to see if we can publish a fix.

Comment: Updated and with stacktrace. Seem like the combination package="com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.extension" and <activity android:name=".q.SamplePreferenceActivity" does not work.